# Delphi drawing part of png file on another image

Tags: delphi, png, transparency, delphi-xe2

I am using this function to draw a png over a TImage on a specific location:

```
procedure TForm1.PlacePNG(nam: string; px, py: Integer);
var
  vPic: TPicture;
  vSrc: TGraphic;
begin
  vPic := TPicture.Create;
  try
    vPic.LoadFromFile(Nam);
    vSrc := vPic.Graphic;
    Image1.Canvas.Draw(px, py, vSrc);
  finally
    vPic.Free;
  end;
end;
```

My question: what is the best way to do this with **part** of the png file, without losing its transparency?

Answer (score 5):

This is an interesting question!

Of course, drawing the *entire* PNG is trivial:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  bg, fg: TPngImage;
begin

  bg := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    bg.LoadFromFile('K:\bg.png');
    fg := TPngImage.Create;
    try
      fg.LoadFromFile('K:\fg.png');
      Image1.Picture.Graphic := bg;
      Image2.Picture.Graphic := fg;
      fg.Draw(bg.Canvas, Rect(0, 0, fg.Width, fg.Height));
      Image3.Picture.Graphic := bg;
    finally
      fg.Free;
    end;
  finally
    bg.Free;
  end;

end;
```

[image: Output]

To draw only a part, *one* possible solution is to obtain the images as 32-bpp RGBA bitmaps and then use the Windows API, specifically, the [`AlphaBlend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-alphablend) function:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  bg, fg: TPngImage;
  bgbm, fgbm: TBitmap;
  BlendFunction: TBlendFunction;
begin

  // Load background PNG
  bg := TPngImage.Create;
  try

    bg.LoadFromFile('K:\bg.png');

    // Load foreground PNG
    fg := TPngImage.Create;
    try

      fg.LoadFromFile('K:\fg.png');

      // Preview background and foreground
      Image1.Picture.Graphic := bg;
      Image2.Picture.Graphic := fg;

      // Create background BMP
      bgbm := TBitmap.Create;
      try

        bgbm.Assign(bg);

        // Create foreground BMP
        fgbm := TBitmap.Create;
        try

          fgbm.Assign(fg);

          // Blend PART OF foreground BMP onto background BMP
          BlendFunction.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
          BlendFunction.BlendFlags := 0;
          BlendFunction.SourceConstantAlpha := 255;
          BlendFunction.AlphaFormat := AC_SRC_ALPHA;
          if not Winapi.Windows.AlphaBlend(
            bgbm.Canvas.Handle,
            100,
            100,
            200,
            200,
            fgbm.Canvas.Handle,
            200,
            200,
            200,
            200,
            BlendFunction
          ) then
            RaiseLastOSError;

          // Preview result
          Image3.Picture.Graphic := bgbm;

        finally
          fgbm.Free;
        end;

      finally
        bgbm.Free;
      end;

    finally
      fg.Free;
    end;

  finally
    bg.Free;
  end;

end;
```

[image: Output]

Comment: It doesn't work for me.
System Error. code:87. The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: @OferLeshem: Are you sure you converted the PNGs into bitmaps? You will get that error message if you try to use `AlphaBlend` with the `MyPng.Canvas.Handle`.

Comment: I don't have Delphi installed at the moment to test this, but does [`TCanvas.CopyRect()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.CopyRect) work in this situation?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: No, that doesn't work with the alpha channel. Internally, it uses `StretchBlt`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I adapted it with D7 to [PngImage 2.0's `TPngObject`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pngdelphi2/) (using ZLib 1.2.8) and also get `$00000087`, even making sure both rects are within bounds and don't overlap. I guess my `TBitmap` version is too old, not supporting/expecting RGBA.

Comment: @AmigoJack: The 10.3 `PngImage.pas` is different.

Comment: For instance, the `AssignTo` method is different. That might be the issue.